# Highlight the word in array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 issues:

1. Array split functionality as I cannot use it not sure why?
2. Words are not highlighting.

```js
const text = [
        `Jelly sweet roll jelly beans biscuit pie macaroon chocolate donut. Carrot cake caramels pie sweet apple pie tiramisu carrot cake. Marzipan marshmallow croissant`  
    ]; // this is what i want to use instead of 'p' but also below not working
    function selectWord() {
        //const p = document.querySelector('p');
        text.innerHTML = text.innerText
            .split('')
            .map((word) =>
                word.length > 5 ? `<span class="lightext">${word}</span>` : word
            )
            .join('');
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .lightext {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is the extremely long paragraph that we want to highlight all words longer than eight characters in.</p>
</body>
<script src="app1.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: You're never calling `selectWord()`.

Comment: Do you mean to split on a space or an empty string?

Comment: @lusc i called and still no difference.

Comment: @phatfingers I want to select array text and trying to find the words which have length more then X char and trying to highlight.

Comment: Why is it an array of one element?

Comment: @Andy my array has a paragraph and not just 1 element.

Comment: That is an array with one element which is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply fixed the obvious bugs in your code. Most notably, splitting words on spaces (where you had an empty string) and then reassembling them by the same.

```js
    function selectWord() {
        const p = document.querySelector('p');
        console.log(p.innerText.split(' '));
        p.innerHTML = p.innerText
            .split(' ')
            .map((word) =>
                word.length > 5 ? `<span class="lightext">${word}</span>` : word
            )
            .join(' ');
    }
    selectWord();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .lightext {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is the extremely long paragraph that we want to highlight all words longer than eight characters in.</p>
</body>
<script src="app1.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

So, there are a few issues. I assume you changed the code for testing because you're not calling the function `selectWord()` anywhere (and the element is commented out).

You cannot use `.split('')` because that breaks strings into individual characters, not words, so everything has a length of 1. You need to change both your `split` and `join` to be `.split(' ')` and `.join(' ')`.

Please also note, your `text` variable is an array, not a DOM object. Therefore it does not posses the `innerHTML` and `innerText` properties

The correct script would be.

```js
function selectWord(str) {
  const el = document.querySelector("p")
  const highlightedText = str.split(' ').map((word) => word.length > 5 ? `<span class="lightext">${word}</span>` : word).join(' ')
  el.innerHTML = highlightedText
}

selectWord('this is a longer string than normal')
```

Comment: Thanks all for swift replies. All solution's worked. Though for array of text i believe i have iterate through it and not doing it above way. Correct?

Comment: @kohatian Yes, you would need to do a loop and call selectWord (or put the loop inside selectWord), if you want this to work with an array. Keep in mind that this appends to a single element and loops would override the existing text inside that element so only the last element's text in the array would be visible inside the `<p>` (using this example) you'd need to adapt the script slightly to append to the text instead (or however you want to handle it)

Answer (score 1):

1. selectWord function was never called
2. The text should not be an array but a string
3. In split and in join, you should have a string with a space to break up the words. An empty string will split all characters

```js
const text = `Jelly sweet roll jelly beans biscuit pie macaroon chocolate donut. Carrot cake caramels pie sweet apple pie tiramisu carrot cake. Marzipan marshmallow croissant`; // this is what i want to use instead of 'p' but also below not working
    function selectWord() {
        const p = document.querySelector('p');
        p.innerHTML = text
            .split(' ')
            .map((word) =>
                word.length > 5 ? `<span class="lightext">${word}</span>` : word
            )
            .join(' ');
    }
    selectWord();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .lightext {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This is the extremely long paragraph that we want to highlight all words longer than eight characters in.</p>
</body>
<script src="app1.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with fewer steps (no splitting, mapping, or joining) would be to use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression to identify words that have more than 5 letters, and then attach the paragraph as HTML to the document body with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

```js
const arr = [
  'Jelly sweet roll jelly beans biscuit pie macaroon chocolate donut. Carrot cake caramels pie sweet apple pie tiramisu carrot cake. Marzipan marshmallow croissant',
  'Moon gopher travel onomatopoeia volcano tree'
];

function highlightWords(text, regex) {
  return text.replace(regex, (word) => {
    return `<span class="highlight">${word}</span>`;
  });
}

const regex = /[a-zA-Z]{6,}/g;
const { body } = document;

for (const text of arr) {
  const para = `<p>${highlightWords(text, regex)}</p>`;
  body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', para);
}
```

```css
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```